# How to apply CSS in a generated HTML table (with mysql data)?

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablesorter

Let me start with the fact that I'm using `tablesorter` (which is GREAT http://tablesorter.com/docs/ )

Now, I have this HTML and PHP code:

```
<table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Max.View</th>
      <th>Portefeille</th>
      <th>Groep</th>
      <th>Aantal</th>
      <th>Aanschafkoers</th>
      <th>Aanschaf Euro</th>
      <th>Aandeel</th>
      <th>Vandaag</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php 
  $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','altered','altered');
  mysql_select_db("altered",$conn);

  $query1 = "select * from data";
  $get = mysql_query($query1);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
?>
    <tr> <!-- WARNING: this was missing in the original -->
      <td><?php echo "<img heigth=90 width=260 border=1 vspace=2 hspace=2 align=middle src=".$row['bigview']."?=rand(1,999)/>" ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['fname'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['mi'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['age'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['age'] * $row['gender'] ?></td>
      <td align="right"><?php print "<a href='$row[URL]'> $row[lname] </a>";       ?></td>
      <td ><?php echo "<img heigth=90 width=260 border=1 vspace=2 hspace=2 src=".$row['address']."?=".rand(1,999)."/>" ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to apply this CSS on it...

http://dapinder.com/zoom-images-on-mouse-hover-using-css3/

> (there are lots of other examples:
>   http://stanhub.com/how-to-create-zoom-effect-on-image-hover-with-css-and-jquery/)
>   But they question remains for all the same. (How do I apply it on a
>   generated table with mysql data?)

to be more precise, I want it to be used on the last column....

Question 1: Do I have to apply the `class=zoom_img` on the Upper part somewhere at the `thead` `th` vandaag?

or

do I have to apply it on the last part, the part with the

```
<td><?php echo "<img
```

I tried that . for example this:

```
<td ><?php echo "<img class=zoom_img hei
```

but nothing happens...

Question 2: Do I really need to use the DIV just like in the example. If yes, where exactly should I use it?

Also, the example shows with the double quotes....:

```
<div class="zoom_img">
  <img src="image.png" title="Magify image on mouse hover using CSS" />
</div>
```

....but how should it be formatted in this line:

```
<td ><?php echo "<img class=zoom_img heigth=90 width=260 border=1 vspace=2 hspace=2 src=".$row['address']."?=".rand(1,999)."/>" ?></td>
```

Can I use it without the double quotes like with `heigth=90`?
or
Does it need the double quotes because it's CSS (or something)?

Comment: If you want to apply css to the last column, this should work: td:last-child {/*your styles here*/}

Comment: that answer is to short for me to understant. , where to put this td:last-child {/*your styles here*/}

Comment: Wherever is the css of your table, and then any css you put between {} should apply to the last column of your table.

Comment: this works:

    <td class="zoomimg"><?php echo "<img src=".$row['address']."?=rand(1,999)/>" ?></td>

so i had to remove: 
heigth=90 width=260 border=1 vspace=2 hspace=2 align=middle

apparently it was conflicting with css

Answer (score 0):

you can escape double quotes in PHP:

```
<?php echo "<img class=\"zoom\"_img heigth=\"90\" width=\"260\" border=\"1\" vspace=\"2\" hspace=\"2\" class=\"yourclass\" src=".$row['address']."?=".rand(1,999)."/>" ?>
```

but better outsource the CSS in a .css file and just add `class="yourclass"`

You can try to see an example of your output in your environment, only with html/css, so you can see that the CSS3 you want to apply works, and then escape it and do whatever you need with PHP. And you already know how to escape the `"`